# Github-pages showing only front-matter

Tags: yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I'm unable to see the `index.html` get rendered with jekyll's front matter. In fact, the front matter is all I see on the webpage.

[image: page not rendering]

Here is the folder layout:
[image]

and the `_config.yml`:

```
title: badabing badaboom
email: xyz@gmail.com
description: tbd
#baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: 
github_username: 
encoding: utf-8
# Build settings
theme: jekyll-theme-clean-blog
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
remote_theme:  StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-clean-blog-jekyll 
# Exclude from processing.
# The following items will not be processed, by default.
# Any item listed under the `exclude:` key here will be automatically added to
# the internal "default list".
#
# Excluded items can be processed by explicitly listing the directories or
# their entries' file path in the `include:` list.
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this, or what I should look into?

Answer (score 1):

My god... *facepalm
I just needed to get rid of `.nojekyll`

> GitHub Pages will use Jekyll to build your site by default. If you
> want to use a static site generator other than Jekyll, disable the
> Jekyll build process by creating an empty file called .nojekyll in the
> root of your publishing source, then follow your static site
> generator's instructions to build your site locally.